# Saving file path to database, only saves the file name

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok So I have been searching all over have come to this little bit of code and got almost everything to work. I can upload an image and save it to the folder that was created. I can save the the other values pass to the database as well. My problem now is that i want to save the file path to the data base so i can call it to display the image on another page. For some reason it will only save the image's name that is being uploaded and not the path.

When i debug it and see what all is getting passed, when i add a watch to
 `file.SaveAs(pathLoc);`

> Expression has been evaluated and has no value    void

Here is the code I've beed using

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ImageInfo info, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                var pic = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName); 
                var pathLoc = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + pic);
                file.SaveAs(pathLoc);


                info.ImagePath = file.FileName;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(info);
    }
```

**View**

```
 <h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ImageInfoes", null, FormMethod.Post,     new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ImageInfo</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageSize, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageSize, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageSize, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="ImagePath" title="Upload a product image" type="file" name="file" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 }

    <div>
       @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
   </div>
```

**Model**

```
    public partial class ImageInfo
   {
      public byte id { get; set; }
      public string ImageName { get; set; }
      public Nullable<long> ImageSize { get; set; }
      public string ImagePath { get; set; }
   }
```

Anything would be help full.

Comment: info.ImagePath = file.FileName; => FileName will only give you the file... name.

Comment: Set `pathLoc` instead of `file.Filename` ?

Comment: When i change it from file.FileName to pathLoc the db.SaveChanges();  throws and error.

Comment: `info.ImagePath = file.FileName;` is assigning just the file name - it needs to be `info.ImagePath = pathLoc;` if you want the path. What is the error you getting? Best guess is that you have a max length on the field and your exceeding it.

Comment: And note that the _Expression has been evaluated and has no value void_ message is just telling you that the `.SaveAs()` method does not return a value (its signature is `public virtual void SaveAs(string filename
)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, full path you need to combine file path and file name both.

```
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()));
```

> C:\Users\02483695\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\Cons
>   oleApplication5\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.exe\tv1k1uev.jsq

Also below you may find a sample about file, file directory, file path and file extension.

```
System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("filename.file");
var fileDirectory = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
var fileName = fileInfo.Name;
var fileExtension = fileInfo.Extension;
var filePathandFileNameBoth = fileInfo.FullName;

Console.WriteLine("filePathandFileNameBoth: ");
Console.WriteLine(filePathandFileNameBoth);
Console.WriteLine("-");
Console.WriteLine("fileDirectory:");
Console.WriteLine(fileDirectory);
Console.WriteLine("-");
Console.WriteLine("fileName:");
Console.WriteLine(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("-");
Console.WriteLine(filePathandFileNameBoth == fileDirectory + "\\" + fileName ? fileExtension : "I'm totally wrong");
Console.ReadLine();
```

as a result:
[image: Console Output]

Comment: isnt that what im am doing with the `var pathLoc = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + pic);`?

Comment: This "info.ImagePath = file.FileName;" is the location which you're doing wrong. That's why I explained all "FileInfo" object properties about directory/path/fullpath and extension.